# Laravel - How to properly route a button to a controller function?

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I have a button that redirects to confirmDelete route:

```
<td align="center"><button type="button" data-href="{{route('head.sale.h_2_101@confirmDelete', ['id' => $No-1])}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Confirm Delete</button></td>
```

I also set up the route in web.php:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'head/sale/h_2_101/confirmDelete/{id}', 'head\sale\h_2_101@confirmDelete')->name("head.sale.h_2_101@confirmDelete")->middleware('auth');
```

It redirects to this function inside h_2_101.php Controller:

```
public function comfirmDelete($id) {
    View::share('deleteUrl', route('head.sale.h_2_101@delete', ['id' => $id]));
    View::share('backUrl', "javascript:history.back()");

    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
```

But when I press on the Confirm Delete button, it gives me this error:

[image]

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Do you have your namespaces set correctly? Should be `namespace App\Http\Controllers\head\sale;`. Is your class `class h_2_101 extends Controller { ... }`? Show your Controller declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Type error you wrote confirmDelete on route but the function name is co'm'firmDelete.

Answer (score 0):

Your method in the controller is `comfirmDelete` and in the route is `confirmDelete` that is the problem.